# URL builder replaces space with dash

Tags: php

I have rather limited PHP knowledge but and I'm trying to debug an issue with my site's search function. The search keyword is returned via

```
$_POST['keywords']
```

Page number links are generated via

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('keywords' => $_POST['keywords'], 'page' => $page), null, true); ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a>
```

For some odd reason, say I search for "hello world" and try to view another page of results, the search term in the url line is changed to "hello-world" which messes up the search. I tried using PHP's urlencode in the following manner which didn't do anything:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('keywords' => urlencode($_POST['keywords']), 'page' => $page), null, true); ?>"><?php echo $page; ?></a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suppose one approach might be to use `str_replace('-', ' ', $_POST['keywords'])` but then you run the risk of removing `-` that were supposed to be there. Like a hyphenated last name or something.

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: Just passing through on review.  A little more detail about your `$this->url` method would go a long way toward getting a useful answer.  Ditto on the framework comment if you're using one too.